# How to use an ouput parameter of a stored procedure in an update statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

```
 update rd 
 set rd.Identifier = isnull(rd.Identifier1,exec DBName.dbo.GenerateUniqueIdSP  @UniqueId OUTPUT)
 from [Try]..RawData rd with (nolock) where rd.Id in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

In the above code I need to update the `Identifier` column with the newly generated `UniqueId` but I should not use a variable to hold the output value because I have to update multiple rows in a batch.

I am getting an error in the above code.

What needs to be changed?

Comment: For starters, you can't do `ISNULL(something, EXEC sp)`

Comment: `I am getting an error in the above code.`  Don't leave us in suspense, what's the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to change  your `stored procedure` into a `function` 
or you need to use `CURSOR` and do the update inside the cursor loop.

with function your update statement looks like this

```
 update rd 
 set rd.Identifier = dbo.GenerateUniqueIdFn()
 from [Try]..RawData rd  
 where rd.Id in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) and
 rd.Identifier1 is NULL
```

with cursor it will look like this

```
DECLARE updateIdentCur CURSOR FOR
select rd.Id from [Try]..RawData rd  
where rd.Id in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) and
rd.Identifier1 is NULL


OPEN updateIdentCur 
    FETCH NEXT FROM updateIdentCur into @rId

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    exec DBName.dbo.GenerateUniqueIdSP  @UniqueId OUTPUT
    UPDATE set rd.Identifier = @UniqueId
    Where rd.Id = @rId
    FETCH NEXT FROM updateIdentCur into @rId
end

close  updateIdentCur 
deallocate  updateIdentCur
```

Comment: Thanks for the work around Rajesh. But my problem is that I have been told not to use any kind of loops or cursors and the system only this Stored proc in all the places so i might not be allowed to change it to a function(i will try to talk about this with my senior though). Is there any other way i can do this without using loops? If not i will have to use this method.

Comment: @Pravin, another way is to declare a temporary table and generate  that many uniqueids using the stored procedure and use them